# FirstValue and NthValue Django window function not working as expected

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following query

```
grouped_data = (
    Notification.objects
    .filter(type=2, user=18, is_removed=False)
    .values('question')
    .annotate(
        total_likes=Count('user'),
        most_recent_at=Max('created_at'),
        is_read=Min('is_read'),
        first_actor=Window(expression=FirstValue('actor_id'), order_by=F('id').desc(), partition_by=['question_id']),
        second_actor=Window(expression=NthValue('actor_id', 2), order_by=F('id').desc(),partition_by=['question_id']),
    ).order_by('-total_likes')
)
```

Here's my Notification model:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='actors')
    actor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='users')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(NotifType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_removed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

For some reason, `second_actor` is always `None` and the `first_actor` is always the very first actor id and not the latest actors. For example, if I have:

```
id  actor_id
20  10
19  21
18  3
```

I'd expect `first_actor` to be 10 and `second_actor` to be 21. What I get is `first_actor` as 3 and `second_actor` as `None`.

Why is this happening? My underlying database is MySQL...when I do a raw query in MySQL I get the correct result.